# How can I use Proguard in Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

How can I use Proguard in titanium or is there any similar functionality in order to make de-compile of codes harder to achieve? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching this myself and found that it can be done.  However there are open tickets in Appcelerator's jira regarding issues doing so.  The best example I have found is this repo at Github, https://gist.github.com/marshall/799497 that is a simple application with proguard configuration.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the security and also reduce the app size check out this **ProGuard Plugin** (read the description along with Jira's inputs for exact details):

[Android: Automatically generate ProGuard configuration file](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14740)